# Azure Messages Timestamp

Tags: azure

Is there anyway to get a timestamp as to when a message is placed on my Azure queue? What is the best way?

For example, a partner sends a message to my queue and I want to know the time the partner placed a specific message in the queue.

Thanks

Comment: Data queue or message queue?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the .NET API, the property [InsertionTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueuemessage.insertiontime.aspx) in the CloudQueueMessage you get when fetching a message or peeking the queue will contain;

> The time that that message was added to the queue.

Comment: Do you have a sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, in Java code the following would retrieve a message (then get the insertion time) and then peek at the next message (and get its insertion time.) This also shows how access to the queue can be controlled by using a revocable stored access policy string.

```
public class Dequeue {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException 
{               
String sas = "sv=2012-02-12&sig=XUHWUy2ayrcEjNvZUhcgdPbgKZflwSXxtr0BH87XRII%3D&si=heath";           
StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature credentials = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(sas);                 
URI baseuri = new URI("http://grassy.queue.core.windows.net");
CloudQueueClient queueClient = new CloudQueueClient(baseuri,credentials); 
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference("queue1");
CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = queue.retrieveMessage();
System.out.println(retrievedMessage.getMessageContentAsString());
System.out.println(retrievedMessage.getInsertionTime());
queue.deleteMessage(retrievedMessage);
CloudQueueMessage peekedMessage = queue.peekMessage();
System.out.println(peekedMessage.getMessageContentAsString());
System.out.println(peekedMessage.getInsertionTime());               
} }
```